# How to get API data from the useEffect and use a specific one based on the Pokemon I click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pokemon-go

I am trying to Onclick on pokemon img to get that specific pokemon and navigate it to another page. In React Btw

This is where I list all the pokemons
Example.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
    const PokeArr = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=40");
            const allPoke = res.data.results;
            setKantoPokemon(allPoke);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error + " This is the error");
        }
    };

    PokeArr(); 
}, []);
```

This is my attempt of the function

```
const ClickPoke =  async() => {
        try{
            const gettinPoke = (async(pokemon) => {

             
            const res = await fetch (pokemon.url);
                const data = res.json()
                setclickpokedata(data)
                navigate("./Clicked", {state: {clickpokedata: res.data} });
                console.log(gettinPoke)
            }) 
        } catch{
            console.error(error + "That Was the error")
        }
          
};
```

I've tried this function above but if anyone could explain what I am doing wrong so I can get something out of this?

Comment: Why don't you use [`react-router`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main)?

Comment: I think you are not calling the function which fetches the pokemon data viz gettinPoke. Also you have console.log statement inside this same function which is just logging the function.

Comment: i have react-router in the app.jsx, but it wont even send anything to the new file i am trying to send it to